# In-script command to copy all do files in the current directory to another folder in Stata

Tags: stata

The following is the copy command.

```
copy "main.do" "main2.do", replace
```

However, I want to copy all do files in the current directory, and paste to another directory. I hope this is done without me needing to specify the file names of each do file. How is this possible?

From link https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-08/msg00620.html

I tried

```
cd "C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\test"
local files : dir "`c(pwd)'" files "*.do"
foreach file in `files' {
    copy `file' "`file'_copied"
}
```

so I could at least copy within the current folder. But I still don't know how to copy all files to another folder.

======================

Second solution.

Can I just get the filename of the current do-file, and then copy this do file into another folder?

This http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1297295-obtain-name-of-current-do-file

talks about something, but "c(tmpdir)" only obtains directory name.

==========================

I did more research and found this https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s457628.html

Comment: Please ask separate questions in separate posts. That lets people who might answer pick and choose and it makes the forum clearer for other people. The main purpose here is not to act as a helpline but to build up an archive of useful threads.

Answer (score 1):

Working backwards: the current do-file is not a clearly defined concept. Do-files can be nested, so Stata could start with `a.do` which calls `b.do` which calls `c.do` .... So, what's the current do-file? All of them.

As you nearly say, you can get a list of files of a certain kind in the current directory by (e.g.)

```
local filelist : dir . files "*.do"
```

Copying to `bar` just requires you to mention `bar`, although it seems you want to change the filename too:

```
foreach f of local filelist { 
    local F : subinstr local f ".do" "2.do", all  
    copy `f'  bar/`F' 
}
```

Using a forward slash is prudent even under Windows. [See the discussion here and its references.](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0042)

Useful functions here are documented [online](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?extended_fcn) and correspondingly within Stata:

```
 help extended fcn
```

Comment: Thank you! The command mvfiles (which I have to install by ssc) allowed me to move all .do files in the current directory to another directory. By "current" do file, yes it may have ambiguous meaning. It could be just a.do. It will be good if, I will write the codes for copying files within a.do file then a.do file is copied to another folder. Alternatively, it could be all of a.do and b.do and c.do (which are run by a.do) that are copied to another folder, but not d.do (which is not run by a.do). If things like this can be made, that will be fantastic. I will never lose sight of what I ran.